# How to use an ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets that references cells in the same column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, count, sequence, array-formulas

After getting sick and tired of having to copy formulas back into my sheet anytime I needed to add a row (one of my gripes of Google Sheets where Excel is much better). I've decided to try using `ARRAYFORMULA` in row 2 of all my sheets to basically make column formulas. Google Support pages suggests this is an exact replacement for the functionality in Excel - it's not). Note that I don't think either Excel or Google does Column formulas well - but Excel definitely does it better then Google Sheets in this case.

### Background

Just using `ARRAYFORMULA` with a known range works well anytime I add a row in the MIDDLE of that range. However, it doesn't work well when I add a new row to the end of my range that I want to be included. I have to manually change the last row in my `ARRAYFORMULA` formula if I add a row to the end, or I have to make my last row a "dummy" row with a note that says - don't add new rows, always add to the middle and hope other people using the sheet (or even myself) remember to abide by it. Using large sheets with lots of data, one person not following the rule can majorly screw it up for everyone sharing it. I like to have as much automated as possible to minimize costly mistakes.

I tried using `ARRAYFORMULA` using whole columns (e.g. `A:A`, `B:B`, etc.) but if it's a formula where I need a result output to each row (simple example: `= ARRAYFORMULA ( C:C - 1)`, I get an `#N/A` result in the cell and the following error text:

> Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows

**UPDATE**: This error was because the formula was in row 2 and therefore full columns (A:A, B:B, C:C, G:G) were always one more row than what was available in the sheet. Using C$2:C ($ before 2 is necessary), G$2:G, etc. solves that issue.

My workaround for that was to add a cell in a hidden column on my sheets with the following formula:

```
= ARRAYFORMULA( MAX( IF( LEN(A:A), ROW(A:A), ) ) )
```

Note: Whole columns work here because I'm using the MAX function which then returns a single value.

I then name that cell something to the effect of `last_XXXX_row` where `XXXX` is a short version of the name of the sheet so I have a constant I can reference and know what the last active row of the sheet is. Then I protect the cell and hide it.

It gets a little annoying as now I have to use `INDIRECT` everywhere and the formulas get long, but for the most part it works. For example:

```
 = ARRAYFORMULA( ( $C$2:INDIRECT( "$C$" & last_unit_row) = 1 ) )
```

on my "unit" sheet returns TRUE or FALSE based on whether the value in column C is equal to 1 or not and returns the corresponding result in each row of the column I put this in. It's kind of long, but now at least I don't have to enter the formula in every row and then re-enter the formula every time I add a row - whether in the middle or the end of the sheet, it automatically updates the column as I add them. Yay.

**NOTE:** Logic wise, using `$C$2:$C` works and is a much shorter equation. However, I discovered that as you add data, it bogs the spreadsheet down significantly (and it's even slower without the `$`) - so I still recommended using indirect as per my example above, which works much faster.

### Issue

Some formulas do not work as a direct analog when using `ARRAYFORMULA`. For instance, I've learned that the `INDEX` function inside of `ARRAYFORMULA` prevents `ARRAYFORMULA` from executing on the entire array, so have to avoid that. There's probably a few others I haven't tried yet.

My particular issue is in a column that needs to know something in the column above it. In both Excel and Google Sheets I often use a count up / reset column to track how many entries there are in a given category. For example, such a formula in column B dependent on a category value in column G typically looks like this:

```
= IF (G2 <> G1, 0, B1 + 1)
```

Then when I fill down with that formula, it automatically changes all cell references to the needed rows. It's checking a category label in column G - and if that label changes, it resets to 0 (sometimes I reset to 1, depending), otherwise it increments the value in column B. This is helpful when there isn't a uniform number of entries for each category and each entry needs a subindex.

I can't seem to get this to work using `ARRAYFORMULA`.

### Attempted Solutions

I tried this:

```
= ARRAYFORMULA( IF( $G2:INDIRECT( "$G$" & last_item_row ) <> $G1:INDIRECT( "$G$" & ( last_item_row - 1 ) ), 0, $B1:INDIRECT( "$B$" & ( last_item_row -1 ) ) ) )
```

And I get a `#REF` result in the cell with the error text:

```
Circular Dependency Detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Settings
```

So... it *sort of* makes sense as it appears that there's a reference to the cell the formula is in inside the range that's created by `INDIRECT`. However, if the formula was executed properly, it's would always calculate based on the cell ABOVE it and never actually use its own cell as part of the calculation.

If I could use `INDEX` instead of `INDIRECT` I ought to be able to avoid this, but I can't.

UPDATE: This formula is basically correct mathematically:

```
= ARRAYFORMULA ( IF( $G$1:INDIRECT( "$G$" & ( last_item_row - 1 ) ) <> $G$2:INDIRECT( "$G$" & ( last_item_row ) ), 0, ($B$1:INDIRECT( "$B$" & ( last_item_row - 1 ) ) + 1 ) ) )
```

However, it requires that Iterative calculations are turned on, and it has a maximum value it will "max out" at based on the number of iterations allowed - and there are diminishing returns as the number of iterations is increased. At 100 iterations, it maxes at 10 - my real data has some categories that have 25 sub indices and the spreadsheet gets slower to calculate as iterations goes up, so this isn't a viable solution.

Am I overcomplicating this? Is there a simpler solution I'm not seeing? I'm trying to us `COUNTIF` as well [ Non-Array version of the formula that works when filled down: `=COUNTIF($G$1:$G1,$G2)` ], but haven't gotten it to work.

Closest `ARRAYFORMULA` version I have is this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( COUNTIF($G$1:($G1:INDIRECT( "$G$" & ( last_item_row - 1 ) ) ), $G2:INDIRECT( "$G$" & last_item_row ) ) )
```

I'm surprised that even worked at all - it returns array values, but it gets me the total number of times that category appears in every row, instead of just the ones leading up to that row.

### Example

[image: Sub Index Example]

The example above, which uses the formula `= if( B2<>B1, 0, A1 + 1 )` in Cell A2 and filled down to cell A13, shows example input (Category) and the desired output (Sub Index). With this formula, however, if I add to cell B14, A14 will not populate unless I copy and paste or fill the formula down to the next row. I want an `ARRAYFORMULA` in Cell A2 that will automatically fill the cells below it when I add additional data in column B (whether below or by adding a row in between) without having to touch the formula again.

Comment: Hi, can you show the input and the desired output?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I added an example to my question, as requested.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried using ARRAYFORMULA using whole columns (e.g. A:A, B:B, etc.) but if it's a formula where I need a result output to each row

you can always freeze it like:

```
=INDIRECT("A:A")
```

this way you can add rows anywhere you want (if you of course not add new row above the row that holds the formula - that would be troublesome to fit in A:A into A2:A)

---

> that the INDEX function just does not work with ARRAYFORMULA at all

INDEX is already ARRAYFORMMULA type of formula. the analogy being here as: you need a car to get from A to B where INDEX is a blue car with 3 doors and ARRAYFORMULA is a red car with 5 doors - it doesn't matter what color you have, you just need a car

---

> `= IF (G2 <> G1, 0, B1 + 1)`

while this is direct logic there are several ways how to achieve the same thing. proper usage would require not to use such formulas as ARRAYFORMULA in column G or B to avoid circular dependency errors. for a simple resetting count up try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(B1:B7, B1:B7, 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(B1:B7)),"<="&SEQUENCE(ROWS(B1:B7))))
```

[image]

feel free to change B1:B7 to open range or frozen range...

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="";; COUNTIFS(B2:B; B2:B; 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:B)); "<="&SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:B)))-1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the goal. I want an `ARRAYFORMULA` in Row 2 of one column that will populate as many rows in the column as there are in the other columns in the table as described in this Google Support Article (and linked example) https://support.google.com/docs/thread/7173404/insert-new-rows-and-include-all-formulas?hl=en. I have it working in all columns (so far) except this one. You definitely cannot do that with `INDEX` - only `ARRAYFORUMULA` can do that

Comment: @Trashman see the updated answer

Comment: Thank you! I've never used `SEQUENCE` before, but that works perfectly. It also showed me I was overcomplicating all my other formulas with my use of `INDIRECT` and my last row formula. B:B always gives an error with the formula at B2 because it's always one more row than I have. B2:B is always exactly the rows I need. D'oh! Before I accept as final answer, please make one change: `INDIRECT` is not necessary, so you can replace all the `INDIRECT` with just $B$2:$B ($ are necessary).  I was using `INDIRECT` because I thought I needed to include my `last_unit_row` variable.

Comment: Actually, further iteration: the only $ necessary is the one on the 2. So B$2:B can replace the `INDIRECT` statements.

Comment: Or no $ at all :-D

Comment: FYI to all: When I implemented this, it worked well at first but eventually made my sheet SUPER SLOW as I added more rows. I'm still using player0's basic solution using `INDEX`, `COUNTIFS` and `SEQUENCE` but rather than as written (and how I requested), I now put back in all the $'s and go back to using `$B$2:INDIRECT( "$B$" & last_item_row )` where `last_item_row` points to a cell with equation `= ARRAYFORMULA( MAX( IF( LEN(A:A), ROW(A:A), ) ) )` It makes for a terribly huge, awkward final equation, but now my sheet executes MUCH, MUCH faster than leaving in `B2:B`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the
`INDEX`
function with
`MATCH`
instead of
`INDIRECT`
in your
`ARRAYFORMULA`
For example, if your data is in the range
`A1:A11`
, and you want to retrieve the value at row 5 through
`INDIRECT`
, you would use:
`=INDIRECT("A" & 5)`
If you want to retrieve the value at row 5 through
`INDEX`
, you would use:
`=INDEX(A:A, 5)`
Now, if you want to use the
`INDEX`
function with
`ARRAYFORMULA`
, you will need to use the
`MATCH`
function to find the row number of the value you want, since
`INDEX`
only takes a row number as its second argument.
For example, if you want to retrieve the value at row 5 through
`ARRAYFORMULA`
and
`INDEX`/`MATCH`
, you would use:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(5, ROW(A:A))))`
This formula will return the value in
`A5`

Note: In your example, you're trying to match
`$G2`
with
`$G1:$G1`
.  If you want to match
`$G2`
with
`$G1:$G3`
, you would use:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A:A, MATCH($G2, $G1:$G3)))`
This formula will return the value from
`A1`
,
`A2`
, or
`A3`
depending on the value of
`$G2`

Comment: What my original formula does is is compare G2 to G1, G3 to G2, G4 to G3, etc... when there is a change in column G, I want column B to reset to 0 then count up each row until G changes again. Except I have to keep copying that formula to eevery new row. I want one `ARRAYFORMULA` in row 2 that will populate all the rows below similar to the linked example in my comment in the other answer below. Putting INDEX inside of ARRAYFORMULA always collapses to a single value because it's not supported, so that won't work. INDEX alone also won't populate multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Use `SCAN` to get a running total with `OFFSET` to get the previous range.

```
=SCAN(B1,B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),LAMBDA(a,c,if(c=OFFSET(c,-1,0),1+a,0)))
```

| i | Cat |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 0 | B |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | B |
| 0 | A |

Comment: I accepted player0's answer, but I am intrigued by this a bit. I've never used `SCAN` or `LAMBDA`. I prefer the `SEQUENCE` solution ATM because I can understand what that formula is doing. Will this generate an array that will populate the rows below it?

Comment: @Trashman Guess you'll never know whether it'll auto populate. FWIW, I don't think you understand player0's sequence solution either, especially the part where `<=`& is used.